# Modify fast scroll alphabetical bubble

Tags: android, material-design, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-scrollbar, fastscroll

I am trying to change the bubble containing the letter in the scrollbar.

What is its official name BTW ?

I am not talking about the **fastScrollThumbDrawable** or **fastScrollTrackDrawable** on the right side. See the image below.

[image]

1. How to change the color of this bubble ?

[This answer uses colorAccent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576352/change-listviews-scrollbar-fastscroll-color). But I don't want to affect the theme.

2. How to change the position of this bubble ?

The answer from Huby to [How to handle the fast-scroller on Lollipop 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053248/how-to-handle-the-fast-scroller-on-lollipop-5-1) gives a partial answer to the change the location of the bubble

Comment: how to implement such scrollbar first?